# SQL Server Management Studio is not connecting to the server

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server Management Studio isn't connecting to its server. I have tried running configuration services to obtain my server name and it is giving my server name as star. However when I try to connect using server name star or server name `star\MSSQLLocalDB` it's throwing these two errors.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptpJi.jpg) [Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCTNf.jpg)

Comment: If the instance you are running is a default instance, you should be able to connect with the server name only.  If you have a named instance, it would be [servername\instancename].  Can you post the results of:  Select @@servername ?

Comment: Your first screen shot is an error from the client-side Named Pipes provider. In SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLLocalDB is the Named Pipes protocol actually enabled?